# how to check if the pandas merge function has actually merged data as opposed to returning a whole columns with nan?

Tags: python, pandas

I have to merge 2 dataframes: `data` and `cross_join_prom`

```
data = data.merge(cross_join_prom, left_on=['day_dt', 'item_code'], right_on=['day_dt', 'item'], how='left')
```

But it is returning a dataframe with all the columns from `cross_join_prom` with `nan`. Is there a way I can check whether the `merge` function has found common data in the common key, and performed the `merge` functionality?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you think remove `how='left'` for default inner join?

Comment: Try using  `indicator=True` in the merge() call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `indicator=True` option of the [`df.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) call:

From the example below, you can see from the generated `_merge` column which dataframe(s) (left_only, right_only or both) the resulting row is from:

```
np.random.seed(0)
left = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'value': np.random.randn(4)})    
right = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['B', 'D', 'E', 'F'], 'value': np.random.randn(4)})

merged=left.merge(right,on='key',how='outer',indicator=True)
print(merged)

  key   value_x   value_y      _merge
0   A  1.764052       NaN   left_only
1   B  0.400157  1.867558        both
2   C  0.978738       NaN   left_only
3   D  2.240893 -0.977278        both
4   E       NaN  0.950088  right_only
5   F       NaN -0.151357  right_only
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can check if the data type of the columns on which you want to merge are same. Do a `data.dtypes` and `cross_join_prom.dtypes` and check the types for `day_dt`, `item_code`.

Comment: I have, but the thing is, when there is no common day_dt or item_code, the merge doesn't raise an error, but instead gives a dataframe with the merged columns with all nans.